# Can AI/ML be used to decipher unknown text on such a low resolution scale of one or two letters to a pixel by color?

Tags: machine-learning, optical-character-recognition, image-super-resolution, text-detection

Can an image of unknown text, with resolution of about one or two letters in real life represented by a pixel (like if the image is a photo taken from far away), be used by machine learning or AI to reconstruct the text based on the color of the pixel?

Meaning, if a certain group of letters make a certain colored pixel based on lighting and location, time, distance, etc., can that be reversed engineered to get the original text?

Edit: added if image was a photo taken from far away

Comment: I think it's safe to say no.  At least not at this time.  One pixel is not enough.

Comment: Maybe the exact scene would have to be  re-created exactly?